# SQL: Can you chain table valued functions without using a table variable/temp table?

Tags: sql, function

Is there any way to do something like:

```
select * from dbo.tvFunctionA(select * from dbo.tvFunctionB())
```

without using an intermediate table variable?

The reason I'm asking, is because I have something like this:

```
create function dbo.tvFunctionA()
returns table as return
with B as (
    select * from dbo.tvFunctionB()
)
select
    blah, blah, blah
join B B1 ...
join B B2 ...
...
join B B99 ...
```

and apparently the WITH CTE is low performance.

I would like to speed up the ITVF and am attempting to pull out the CTE table and use it as a parameter.

Comment: `...apparently the WITH CTE is low performance.` Why do you say that?

Comment: in this example, it would seem to be execute the query (select * from dbo.tbFunctionB()) 99 times.  the query in the with () statement happens to be slow so i need to avoid that.

Comment: What on earth are you doing that you need to join to the same table 99 times?

Comment: something along the lines of a pivot.  it's not actually 99 joins, that is for illustration purposes.

Comment: If you really have anything like 99 joins then you would probably get more performance gains from paring that back than from reconfiguring the CTE.

Comment: that's not an option.

Comment: Too many "something likes" for me to see what you are trying to do. Please provide a cut down real example.

Comment: Though you might be interested in http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/

Comment: yeah, that connect article is getting at the same issue.  the "select top (2147483647)" trick is interesting but didn't seem to address my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try these:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (

with B as (
    select * from dbo.tvFunctionB()
)
select
    blah, blah, blah
join B B1 ...
join B B2 ...
...
join B B99 ...

) AS A
```

Comment: i don't really understand what that is going to accomplish.  that should be identical to the code that i'm trying to avoid, no?

Comment: pleas post tvFunctionA script